# detecting the presence of a set of alphanumeric codes in a data frame

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataframe (title: fy14y) with 100 variables (c1 - c100) containing alphanumeric codes of varying length (e.g. 1-S023; 2-Y0408)

What would be the best way to create a binary variable that detects if one or more of the codes from the following list is present in a row?

1-A400,1-A401, 1-A402, 1-A410, 1-A415, 1-A4152, 1-A4158, 1-B377, 1-P360, 1-P362, 1-P364, 1-U900

i.e. 0=if none of them appear, 1=if one or two or three etc. appear once or multiple times.

I've played around with the stringr str_detect function without much luck

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an intuitive way to do this is to put the data in long form, search for a match by `id` and then put it back in wide form. We can do this easily with `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

Using the `df` and `codes_to_check` from the answer by Ronak Shah:

```r
df  |>
    pivot_longer(-id) |>
    mutate(
        row_match = +(any(codes_to_check %in% value)), .by = id
    ) |>
    pivot_wider()

# # A tibble: 4 × 4
#      id row_match c1     c2    
#   <int>     <int> <chr>  <chr> 
# 1     1         1 1-A400 a     
# 2     2         0 a      b     
# 3     3         1 b      1-A401
# 4     4         0 c      d
```

This should be faster than iterating over rows.

Comment: This is a nice solution - what does the `+` do at the start of the condition?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen `any(codes_to_check %in% value)` will return a logical vector. The `+` is just a shorthand for `as.integer()`, i.e. if you type `+TRUE` into the R console it will return `1` (and the `class()` of that `1` will be integer rather than numeric).

Comment: I learn something new every day.  Thank you!  Having checked `?\`+\`` I can see that there are unary and binary forms of `+` and `-` - time for me to get reading.

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen I think most of the time the unary operators act as you would expect but occasionally they can trip you up - if you are not familiar with it already then see [Why are powers of negative numbers wrong?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-are-powers-of-negative-numbers-wrong_003f) in the R FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this base R answer -

```
# Please add all the codes that you want to check
codes_to_check <- c("1-A400","1-A401")
# Columns to check
cols <- paste0("c", 1:100)
df$result <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], `%in%`,codes_to_check)))
df
```

Using a small example -

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:4, c1 = c("1-A400", "a", "b", "c"), 
                 c2 = c("a", "b", "1-A401", "d"))
cols <- paste0("c", 1:2)
df$result <- as.integer(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[cols], `%in%`,codes_to_check)))
df

#  id     c1     c2 result
#1  1 1-A400      a      1
#2  2      a      b      0
#3  3      b 1-A401      1
#4  4      c      d      0
```

---

In `dplyr` we may use `rowwise()` but this might be slower for larger datasets.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(result = as.integer(any(c_across(c1:c2) %in% codes_to_check))) %>%
  ungroup
```